# Integral Too Hard For Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics, special-functions

I have a monstrous integral that I desperately want to solve with *Mathematica*. It takes the form of:

```
Integrate[Exp[-2 t^2] t^(9/5) (x-t)^(4/5) HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1}, {7/5, 19/10}, -t^2], {t, 0, x}]
```

where the numerical parameters can vary a bit. This is just one example. I'm keeping parameters rational in case *Mathematica* sees a trick it can use. What can I do? I would love to use `NIntegrate` but one of the bounds has to be variable. I also substituted it a `Series` approximation to `HypergeometricPFQ`, and that made it integrate, except the series introduced large error.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Try to solve the corresponding differential equation with `NDSolve`.

Comment: `E[-2 t^2]` is not defined.  Did you mean `Exp[-2 t^2]`?

Comment: `f[x_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Exp[-2 t^2] t^(9/5) (x - t)^(4/5) HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1}, {7/5, 
     19/10}, -t^2], {t, 0, x}]` stores the integral as `f`, and allows you to vary the upper limit.  You can try `f[3.2]`.

Comment: @QuantumDot, yes thank you, I changed it. Unfortunately the upper limit has to be $x$, because I'm trying to get out a function of $x$...

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, I've never gone from hypergeometric series to a differential equation before -- can you point me to an example somewhere or a good direction? The reason this integral came up is because it is used to solve the fractional nonlinear Schrodinger equation, so I don't know if going backward, from series to diffeq, would bring me to an easier diffeq that *Mathematica* could solve...

Comment: I was thinking about the fact that if $f(x) = \int_k^x g(t) dt$ then $f(x) = G(x) - G(k)$ where $G'(x) = g(x)$. _Mathematica_ can't do e.g. `Integrate[Sin[t]^Exp[t], {t, 0, x}]` but it can do `NDSolve[f'[x] == Sin[x]^Exp[x] && f[0] == 0, f, {x, 0 10}]` just fine. But maybe this is too simple since you have `x` in the integrand as well...

Comment: I think @MariusLadegårdMeyer is talking about converting your integration into the solution of a differential equation, which is a nice trick in *Mathematica*. I.e. `NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, t}]` is equivalent to `NDSolveValue[{g'[x] == f[x], f[0] == 0}, g, {x, 0, 50}][t]` (as long as you choose `50` to be a large enough number, beyond the maximum `t` you use). The `NDSolve` version is usually much faster than the `NIntegrate` version.

Comment: It seems to work as long as I choose a numeric value for $x$. What a cool method! I don't know if there would be a way to extend it to arbitrary $x$ but it's definitely a start...

Comment: @march, can you post it as an answer, like to upvote.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This problem can be solved numerically by

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{z'[t] == Exp[-2 t^2] t^(9/5) (x - t)^(4/5) 
    HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1}, {7/5, 19/10}, -t^2], z[0] == 0}, z, {t, 0, x}, {x}];
Plot[s[x][x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

As noted by [Marius Ladegård Meyer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/22099/marius-ladeg%C3%A5rd-meyer) in a comment above, `NDSolve` itself is not sufficient, because `x` appears both in the integrand and as the upper limit of integration.

Comment: Beautiful job, thank you! Just out of curiosity, what does the second pair of `[x]` on `s` do in the `Plot` command?

Comment: @Buddhapus  The first `[x]` gives the value of the parameter `{x}` used to solve the ODE.  The second `[x]` gives the value of `t` for which the solution is desired, which happens to be `x` in this case..

Answer (score 8):

Here's an old-school (?) way that takes focused advantage of `NDSolve's` capabilities.  See [Components and Data Structures](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html) for detailed documentation.

`ParametricNDSolve[]` is very convenient, relatively recent, syntactic sugar and fairly well-suited for this problem, as @bbgodfrey's answer shows.  In particular, it's easy to code (except for [the `[x][x]` thing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123725/integral-too-hard-for-mathematica#comment334935_123789) that surprised the OP).  However, it integrates the solution for each distinct `x`. (It caches each solution in case it is reused, up to the cache size limit.)  However the OP's problem can be solved with a single integration over a domain.  Further that domain can be ***extended*** (not recomputed) by `NDSolve` using the documented internal components and data structures.  I always thought this was a neat hook provided by WRI, but I hardly ever see it used.

Let `f[x]` represent the OP's integral.  We can differentiate it to get another integral `fp[x]` that is equal to `f'[x]`.  We can integrate the differential equation `f'[x] == fp[x]` with `NDSolve` up to whatever value of `x` and then extend it when needed.  This can be done automatically with some simple code for the numerical version of `f[x]`, which is called `fN[x]` below. (See **Code Dump** at end.)

There is one hitch to this method. It's a good idea to first call the function on the anticipated domain, so that `NDSolve` can integrate the function once for the domain.  While extending the domain does not require the whole domain to be reintegrated, too many small extensions can be expensive.  For instance,

```
fN[{0, 5}] // AbsoluteTiming
DownValues@fN`df // Length
(*
  {2.11563, {0., 0.47917}}
  77  <-- more on this later
*)
```

Then subsequent calls are very fast:

```
Plot[fN[x], {x, 0, 5}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

If you don't do the initialization of `fN[]` and try to `Plot` `fN[x]`, many of the `Plot` calls to `fN[x]` end up extending the integration interval: that is, `NDSolve` is called many times to take unnecessarily short steps up to whatever value of `x` that `Plot` needs.  This ends up calling the derivative function `df`, which uses `NIntegrate[]` to compute the derivative, a large number of times. (Re-execute the code defining `fN[]` if you wish to test the following; otherwise, it will be fast like above.)

```
Plot[fN[x], {x, 0, 5}] // AbsoluteTiming
DownValues@fN`df // Length
```

[image]

We can see that `df[]` was called 642 times instead of just 76 (one of the down values is the general definition).  That accounts for the difference in speed.

**Code Dump**

I've gotten more used to writing packages, but my early experience has permanently scarred by brain with the impression that I don't know what I'm doing.  Consequently, I conservatively remove from the `` "Global`" `` context all symbols I wish localized in my local context.  (I'm assuming this code will be executed in a notebook in a running session as needed. If you properly pacletize it into a .wl file, prepping the `` "Global`" `` context should be unnecessary.)

I would guess that code for `x < 0` is not needed by the OP (because `f[x]` is real for `x >= 0` and complex for `x < 0`).  Nonetheless, how to include it is shown.  You need separate `NDSolve` calls. `NDSolve` will integrate a singly infinite interval `{x, 0, ±Infinity}`, but not a doubly infinite interval `{x, -Infinity, Infinity}`. (I don't know why; it makes no sense to me, since a finite interval `{x, a, b}` is automatically broken up into `{x, x0, a}` and `{x, x0, b}` when the IC is at `x0` with `a < x0 < b`.)

The derivative `df[]` is memoized because it makes the code run twice as fast. (`NDSolve` must evaluate `df[x]` twice for each `x` on average, I guess.)  If you're concerned about the amount of memory used by memoization (not a problem above), then you can free the memory with `` fN`freeDownValuesDF[] ``.  It won't affect the subsequent speed, since the values are not re-used after the integration by `NDSolve`. (One could add a line to automatically call it after each `` NDSolve`Iterate[..] `` call.)

```
Quiet@Remove["fN`*"];
(* Removes symbols in Global` *)
Remove[fN, state, stateNeg, df, freeDownValuesDF, (* data/funcs *)
  f, \[Xi], x, t]; (* variables *)
ClearAll[fN]; (* create Global` symbol *)
fN // Attributes = {Listable};
Begin["fN`"]; (* Localize auxiliaries *)
(* Redundant with Remove[]; but creates local symbols in fN` *)
ClearAll[state, stateNeg, (* data *)
  f, \[Xi], x, t,(* variables *)
  df, freeDownValuesDF]; (* utilities *)

(* DERIVATIVE OF DESIRED FUNCTION f *)
With[{fp = 
    D[Inactive[Integrate][
      Exp[-2 t^2] t^(9/5) (x - t)^(4/5) HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 
         1}, {7/5, 19/10}, -t^2], {t, 0, x}], x]},
  (* memoization doubles the speed of NDSolve in this case *)
  mem : df[x0_?NumericQ] := mem = Block[{x = x0}, NIntegrate @@ fp];
  ];
(* release memory of memoization *)
freeDownValuesDF[] := DownValues[df] = {Last@DownValues@df};
(* END OF DERIVATIVE CODE *)

(* SOLUTION FOR POSITIVE x *)
{state} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[
   {f'[\[Xi]] == df[\[Xi]], f[0] == 0},
   f, {\[Xi], 0, Infinity}
   (* NDSolve options go here (WorkingPrecision, Method) *)];
NDSolve`Iterate[state, 0.];
fN[x_?NumericQ] /; 
   x > state@"CurrentTime"["Forward"] := (NDSolve`Iterate[state, x];
   First@state@"SolutionVector"["Forward"]);
(* Solution for already solved x *)
fN[x_?NumericQ] /; x >= 0 := f[x] /. NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state];
fN[x_?NumericQ] /; x < 0 := Print["Negative x not implemented."];
(* END OF POSITIVE x CODE *)

(* OMIT IF NEGATIVE x NOT ALLOWED *)
{stateNeg} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[
   {f'[\[Xi]] == df[\[Xi]], f[0] == 0},
   f, {\[Xi], 0, -Infinity}
   (* NDSolve options go here (WorkingPrecision, Method) *)];
NDSolve`Iterate[stateNeg, 0.];
fN[x_?NumericQ] /; 
   x < stateNeg@"CurrentTime"["Backward"] := (NDSolve`Iterate[
    stateNeg, x];
   First@state@"SolutionVector"["Backward"]);
(* Solution for already solved x; overwrites previous def *)
fN[x_?NumericQ] /; x < 0 := f[x] /. NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[stateNeg];
(* END OF NEGATIVE x CODE *)

End[];
```

Answer (score 6):

Problem solved with approximation by sum:

$$\int_0^x \exp \left(-2 t^2\right) t^{9/5} (x-t)^{4/5} \,
   _2F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{7}{5},\frac{19}{10};-t^2\right) \, dt=\\\int_0^x \exp \left(-2 t^2\right)
   t^{9/5} (x-t)^{4/5} \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_k (1)_k\right)
   \left(-t^2\right)^k}{\left(\left(\frac{7}{5}\right)_k \left(\frac{19}{10}\right)_k\right) k!} \,
   dt=\\\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \int_0^x \frac{(-1)^k e^{-2 t^2} t^{\frac{9}{5}+2 k} (-t+x)^{4/5}
   \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_k (1)_k}{k! \left(\frac{7}{5}\right)_k \left(\frac{19}{10}\right)_k} \,
   dt=\\\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{9}{5}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{14}{5}\right) \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{2}+k\right) (-1)^k x^{\frac{18}{5}+2 k} \,
   _2\tilde{F}_2\left(\frac{7}{5}+k,\frac{19}{10}+k;\frac{23}{10}+k,\frac{14}{5}+k;-2 x^2\right)}{8\
   2^{3/5}}$$

```
f[x_, M_] := 1/(8 2^(3/5))*Gamma[9/5] Gamma[14/5] Sum[
Gamma[1/2 + k] (-1)^k x^(18/5 + 2 k)*
HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{7/5 + k, 19/10 + k}, {23/10 + k, 
  14/5 + k}, -2 x^2], {k, 0, M}]

 s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{z'[t] == 
 Exp[-2 t^2] t^(9/5) (x - t)^(4/5) HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 
    1}, {7/5, 19/10}, -t^2], z[0] == 0}, z, {t, 0, x}, {x}];
 Plot[{s[x][x], f[x, 5]}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, {Dashed, Red}},PlotLabels -> {"NDSolve", "Series"}]
```

[image]