# Nintegrate memoization

Tags: numerical-integration, memoization

Is there a way to use memoization for NIntegrate (maybe dependent on the method of integration used) to reduce the number of computations for the same subintervals when computing something like the following?

```
integralFunction[x_] := NIntegrate[(1 + (Sin[t])^2)^(1/2), {t, 0, x}];

parametric[t_] := {t, integralFunction[t]};

ParametricPlot[parametric[t], {t, -π, π}]
```

I would rather not create my own numerical integration function just to use memoization.

Comment: integralFunction[x_] :=   integralFunction[x] =   NIntegrate[(1 + (Sin[t])^2)^(1/2), {t, 0, x}];

Comment: Your function `parametric` can be defined quite simply as the solution of a differential equation.  Mathematica should solve this (numerically) quite easily, and you can evaluate the solution very rapidly.

Comment: @DanielHuber I thought of that, but somehow I thought NIntegrate would still be called multiple times even if integralFunction is saving previous values. Now I realize my mistake. Thx.

Comment: See the part of the code dump in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/287955/4999) labeled `(*SOLUTION FOR POSITIVE x*)` for using `NDSolve` to define a function with arbitrary domain. But if the domain is known ahead of time to be a finite interval -- for instance $[\pi,\pi]$ as in the plot -- then `integralFunction = NDSolveValue[{f'[t] == (1 + (Sin[t])^2)^(1/2), f[0] == 0}, f, {t, -Pi, Pi}]`. This is orders of magnitude better than memoization. (As mikado recommended.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Although your comment doesn't technically answer the question, it does answer for it's intended purpose: about optimizing execution time. As far as I'm concerned you can make it into an actual answer and I'll accept it as such. Thx.